# import requirejs amd module with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, requirejs, amd

I'm using [Converse.js](https://github.com/jcbrand/converse.js) and it's prebuilt into the RequireJS/AMD syntax. Including the file from a CDN you could use it like `require(['converse'], function (converse) { /* .. */ })`. How is it possible to use this with webpack? I would like to bundle converse.js with my webpack output.

I have the file on disk, and want to import it like

```
import converse from './converse.js';
converse.initialize({ .. });
```

Webpack picks up the file and bundles it correctly, although it's not useable yet as it throws 'initialize is not a function'. What am I missing?

Comment: Try to run `console.log(converse)`. What does it print?

Comment: why not use the npm version? https://www.npmjs.com/package/converse.js

Comment: @AndyRay because it's not a module on npm, it's being built and then published. npm is basically 'hosting' the app. i have no idea why it's on npm to be honest..

Comment: @Frxstrem some "Jed" object. using the first code example in my question i have access to a bunch of things, including initialize. if i run the above, i get "initialize is not a function"

Comment: @bitten yeah this is so confusing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the way their bundle is built will not work correctly with how Webpack evaluates modules in a limited context.

From [their builds](https://github.com/jcbrand/converse.js/tree/8bbd88ba862f8ea739ada25a4fc4846b920c717b/dist), taking the built AMD module via NPM without dependencies should be parsable by Webpack and it will enable you to provide the [dependencies](https://github.com/jcbrand/converse.js/blob/8bbd88ba862f8ea739ada25a4fc4846b920c717b/bower.json) to avoid dupes in the final output.

If all else fails, using the [script-loader](https://github.com/webpack/script-loader) will evaluate the script in the global context and you'd get the same experience as if you'd have followed their usage guidelines to reference it from a CDN, just don't forget to configure the globals for your linter.

Comment: so I'm using the scripts loader `import converse from 'script-loader!./node_modules/converse.js/dist/converse.js'` and then later on using the module like `require(['converse'], converse => { .. }` and then webpack complains that is cannot find the module "converse". do you know a way to stop webpack from parsing that require statement?

Comment: i worked it out. in my webpack config i listed converse as an external dep using `externals: { 'converse': 'converse' }`. although it gives me a `1.build.js` file which just contains `module.exports = converse;`. if i *could* have the whole library in this file that would be perfectly, so then it does async load the library which suits my use case perfectly. that's now my next step!

Comment: @bitten `script-loader` should get you there because it just basically writes the whole script as a string in the chunk; make sure you're using the minified sources of converse.js

Comment: yeah i see. so the script loader is including the library as a string. although listing converse as an external, webpack gives me an extra file that seems redundant for me. do you know if there's a way to tell webpack/script-loader to dump the library into the extra file that is generated? so that the library gets async loaded later. i can't seem to work that out, idk if it's even possible.

Comment: i ended up using `script-loader` to load in converse, then telling webpack it's an external and it kinda works. so accepting your answer as it helped me get there.

Comment: Thanks. `script-loader` didn't work for me but `externals` plus @bitten's `require(['converse'], converse => { .. }` did. I load converse.min.js in the html head section to ensure it is loaded before my webpack's consolidated chunk.